# Modifying Page files - "Changes to this file were not saved to file system"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When you open google chrome devtools, and go to Sources and look at the files under Page, how can you modify them and observe changes?

To be more specific, I want to modify some files inside `top/webpack://` when you open Sources, on some websites, to experiment and see how things inside actually work.

But after any changes (Such as inserting a simple `console.log("hello");` inside a .js file), I get "Changes to this file were not saved to file system".

CLARIFICATION: The only solution to "Changes to this file were not saved to file system" warning I've found was [discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654081/change-to-this-file-were-not-saved-to-file-system-error-in-google-chrome-version), but It did not resolve my issue since I can not (don't know how?) to add things from `top/` to workspace.

Comment: What makes you think you should be able to save your changes to someone else's website?

Comment: Eod J.: If you are the same person as ‘‘Joe’’ (the author of this question), please use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are https://superuser.com/users/1060927/joe and https://superuser.com/users/1060954/eod-j.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question and post comments.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks, I haven't noticed I created a separate account when trying to log in via the same gmail account and creating a super user account.

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course the changes won't be saved to the actual site, but to the instance of the site that was served to me? For example, I can easily modify and make changes in the Elements section and they are visible on the site (for me of course, until, for example, the site is refreshed).

Like I can edit the HTML on the ("instance of") site and observe changes, how can I do it with sources as well (For example, modify some javascript that is read from those sources)?

Comment: @Joe AFAIK you can't do that with JS served from elsewhere.

Comment: Sure you can - https://dev.to/apvarun/chrome-devtools-content-overrides-3e79